# Jquery concatenting very simple counter with a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

Following another question, I have a working script to create dynamic form fields : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/uZuWA/4/)

I thought I will figure out the rest, but I do not understand why when I try to assign a new `name` and `ID` attributes to the `textarea`, it gives me `NAN`.

IF I do :

```
i++;
 var newname = jQuery(prevDiv).attr('name');    
prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',i );
```

It sets ok,  But If I try to do :

```
prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',newname +i );
```

..which is what I need - I get `NAN`.

I know my JS qualities are very close to zero, but is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: Your `newname` is `undefined`, and `undefined` plus a number is `NaN`. Use `console.log()` to verify your values are what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `name` attr in your `jQuery(prevDiv)` element. The `name` attribute is actually on the textfield.

Your code should look like this :

```
    var newname = jQuery(prevDiv).find("textarea").attr('name');
    prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',newname + i );
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ny5Y7/

Comment: My god. You again. ( Embarrassed ) I do not know if to laugh or cry . I would stick only to PHP if I could . I can just not get JS (or too tired) . But at least I tried for the last hour :-)

Comment: That's what SO is about, keep up working, your knowledge will increase with practice.

Comment: Actually, I mis-pasted the example, I had `prop()` and not `attr()`

Comment: Old debate: better to use prop() or attr()? As name is an attribute, i find it more logical/readable to use attr()

Comment: I've read somewhere that `prop` will deprecate `attr` in future jQuery releases. So far, I haven't put depth to the practical part of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actually sum the two values: newname is a string and not a number. You will have to cast the variable to a number first and then do the + i. So do this:

```
 prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',parseInt(newname, 10) +i );
```

If you want to concatenate them, then use an extra '':

```
prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',newname + '' + i );
```

Comment: Is still a good habit to specified base when parsing to number, even here, this should not be an issue: parseInt(newname,10)  base 10 coz for string starting with 0, the default parsing use base 8

Comment: good point, I fixed the example

Comment: +1 for the tips . Will try to get my hands on JS.  Thanks. But it appears that I also missed an attribute in the example .

Answer (score 2):

In the first code snippet you provided, the second line should be modified to get the **name** attribute of textarea element present inside the prevDiv as shown below.

```
var newname = jQuery(prevDiv).find('textarea').attr('name');
prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',newname + i );
```

In the your code snippet, you are trying to read the name attribute of prevDiv element which doesn't have any value for it. (So returns undefined)

That is the reason, you get a NAN (Not a number) when adding an undefined with a proper number .

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the wrong syntax. Just force a string there:

```
prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name',newname + ' ' + i );
```

The sum operation was throwing a `NonANumber` or `NaN` error because it was trying to perform arithmetic addition, not string concatenation.

```
var i = 5; // typeof i = number;
var x = i + ""; // typeof x = string;
// or
var y = new String(i);// slower than doing the above.
```